# Application hangs at threading.Timer.start()

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, resize, wxpython

I have a `wx.Frame` from wxPython and want to do intermediate and final updates on resize.

Because I didn't find an end-of-resizing event, my approach is to do the intermediate update on `wx.EVT_SIZE` and the final update in a timer I start on `wx.EVT_SIZE`. It works most of the time, but sometimes it hangs at `threading.Timer.start` (meaning `Before` is printed at last [see code]). Do you know why?

This is the code for the resize handler and the timer method:

```
def _on_resize(self, event):
    self.Layout()
    self._resize_lock.acquire()
    print 'resize event'
    #Intermediate update is done here
    self._resize_lock.release()
    if self._resize_timer != None:
        self._resize_timer.cancel()
    self._resize_timer = threading.Timer(0.75,
        self._resize_timer_method)
    print 'Before'
    self._resize_timer.start()
    print 'After'

def _resize_timer_method(self):
    self._resize_lock.acquire()
    print 'resize timer'
    #Final update is done here
    self._resize_lock.release()
```

PS: If you know how to get an end-of-resizing event, please tell me instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does it have to update during sizing? Regardless, I think you would be better off using a wx.Timer(). I suspect that you're doing something that's not threadsafe and that's making things unpredictable.